# How to use ProgressBar inside nested foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach, progress-bar, nested-loops

How to use Progress Bar properly on a nested foreach loop?
Because I did it like this and my process inside the foreach loop process only does up to the second file I am comparing.

```
int count = d1.GetFiles(fd.fileType, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
int current = 0;
foreach(...)
{
    foreach(...)
    {
      //process
    }
current++;
pbSearch.Value = current / count * 30 + 70;
label1.Text = pbSearch.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: With `went crazy` you are talking about it is very slow, aren't you?

Comment: You need to provide more accurate details to your problem than "went crazy" or people in stackoverflow.com will go crazy too :-)

Comment: I think Progress Bar must a have thread attached to it thats updates the progress bar, this is the right way to go with it. WHy you want progress bar to be updated in nested loop? please explain

Comment: I needed a progress bar because I am comparing too many files.

Comment: use variables that indicate the progress of file (copying deleting etc) as parameters to thread function and update Progress bar according to those params regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your two foreach loops you may consider using two progress bars or recalculate the maximum value, take a look at this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Example:

```
    private void CopyWithProgress(string[] filenames)
    {
        // Display the ProgressBar control.
        pBar1.Visible = true;
        // Set Minimum to 1 to represent the first file being copied.
        pBar1.Minimum = 1;
        // Set Maximum to the total number of files to copy.
        pBar1.Maximum = filenames.Length;
        // Set the initial value of the ProgressBar.
        pBar1.Value = 1;
        // Set the Step property to a value of 1 to represent each file being copied.
        pBar1.Step = 1;

        // Loop through all files to copy. 
        for (int x = 1; x <= filenames.Length; x++)
        {
            // Copy the file and increment the ProgressBar if successful. 
            if(CopyFile(filenames[x-1]) == true)
            {
                // Perform the increment on the ProgressBar.
                pBar1.PerformStep();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. But since I have thousands of files, my tool is lagging... like the toolstrip for displaying the filename being compared is not updating. although when I show a messagebox, it is updating...

Comment: You can call Application.DoEvents(); inside your loop so the progress bar gets updated http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx

Comment: Notice the Caution section in the documentation: Calling this method causes the current thread to be suspended while all waiting window messages are processed. If a message causes an event to be triggered, then other areas of your application code may execute. This can cause your application to exhibit unexpected behaviors that are difficult to debug.